# TimescaleDB grouping statistics by periods

Tags: timescaledb

I’m a newbie in TimescaleDB. I am inspired by this software and I’m going to learn all the documentation, but the number of unusual functions makes even my eyes run away

I need to make statistics on periods (day|week|month|year) for example like this (but not the percentages , but the values):

[image]

What is the optimal query I should make ?

I’ve been thinking about JOIN the table to myself 4 times and using bucket , but it looks scary

Answer (score 2):

You can use [continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/) to create value indicators for different time buckets. This way, the information is generated automatically when you INSERT data to a hypertable.

[You can learn some of the continuous aggregation tricks in this blog post of mine](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/building-cryptocurrency-website).

Comment: As I understand it, you propose to make separate for all periods by MATERIALIZED continues aggregates with bucket like this:  

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW coin_DAY select time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 day', time)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW coin_WEEK select time_bucket(INTERVAL '1 week', time)

But what will the resulting query look like? And should it be the same MATERIALIZED?

Comment: Correct. Exactly like this. If you want the last value you can query it using [last()](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/last/)

Comment: It turns out that I don't need the latest values, but the previous period. I found the LAG() function in the documentation. I made a similar request, how optimal is it? or is it better to use join ?
select
(select lag(value) over (order by bucket) from n_h  order by bucket desc limit 1) as h,
(select lag(value) over (order by bucket) from n_d  order by bucket desc limit 1) as d,
(select lag(value) over (order by bucket) from n_w  order by bucket desc limit 1) as w

Comment: As this is so many new questions, I suggest you open a new question with example code, as this cannot be answered in a comment field and more along with personal tutoring than answering a question. I suggest you try it yourself.